# DevExpress GridControl image column displays images like System.Byte[]

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a table with person data which are Name, Surname, Code and Photo of persons. And when I select persons from table like and send the result to DevExpress GridControl it shows Name, Surname and Code columns. But Photo column displays System.Byte[] value in all rows. What is the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should assign the column's [ColumnEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_ColumnEdittopic) property with an instance of a [RepositoryItemPictureEdit](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemPictureEdittopic).  In this case, the XtraGrid will be able to show image in the grid.

Sample: [How to display an image in GridControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3819)

Related links:

1. [Repositories and Repository Items](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1009)
2. [Inplace Editors Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument745)

Comment: And here's even straight example how to do this [http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3819](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3819)

Answer (score 0):

***Byte Convert To Image

```
           data.Read();

            //get the value of the size field in the current row and store it in filesize

            int fileSize = data.GetInt32(data.GetOrdinal("size"));

            //get the value of the name field in the current row and store it in filesize

            string name = data.GetString(data.GetOrdinal("name"));  

            //Create a byte array to read the file in the row which is in bytes

            byte[] rawData = new byte[fileSize];

            //Read the bytes and store it in the array

            data.GetBytes(data.GetOrdinal("file"), 0, rawData, 0, fileSize);

            //Create the file from the byte array which is read from the database

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

            fs.Write(rawData, 0, fileSize);

            //closing the file stream 

            fs.Close();

            //Showing the image that is just retreived in te picturebox picDB

            picDB.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(name);
```